# double free or corruption (out) when trying to delete Nodes in a Binary tree

Tags: c++, memory-management

I'm trying to make a recursive function to delete all nodes in my binary tree, where p->left and p->right are pointers to the next level in the tree. However it gives the following error message:

*** Error in `./test.out': double free or corruption (out): 0x00007ffdf0cb3650 ***

```
struct Node {
    int key;
    double data;
    Node * right;
    Node * left;
};

void delete_tree(Node * & p){
  if (p->left){
    delete_tree(p->left);
  }
  if (p->right){
    delete_tree(p->right);
  }
  delete p;
};

int main(){
  Node * currentNod = new Node;
  currentNod->key = 5;
  Node * newNode = new Node;
  newNode->key = 3;
  Node * newNode2 = new Node;
  newNode2->key = 6;
  delete_tree(currentNod);
  std::cout << currentNod->key << "\n";
  std::cout << newNode->key << "\n";
  std::cout << currentNod->left->key << "\n";
  return 0;
```

I've searched online and realize there can be problems when you have recursive functions with pointers, however delete_tree takes a reference, not a copy, so that problem should not apply here? I don't understand why it's not working :(

EDIT: Changed the code, the problem was that when I was initializing currentNod I first created a Node object, and then i let currentNod be a pointer to that object. When i instead initialize it like this, it works. However, it does not print what I expect. This prints:

0
3
Segmentation fault

When i would expect it to give segmentation fault right away. Does anyone have an idea what could be the problem now? Thanks :)

Comment: It doesn't matter that the function takes the pointer argument by reference here. But you need to make sure that you do not call `delete_tree` twice (or more) using the same root pointer.

Comment: Show us a [MCVE] please.

Comment: I guess you have circular dependencies in your tree. Maybe Setting `p->left` and `p->right` to `null` after calling `delete_tree` will solve it

Comment: Whenever you are creating a new `Node` make its `left` and `right` as `nullptr` because it may contain some garbage value through which if condition becomes true. show us the code how you are creating and using the `Node` structure.

Comment: Hey sorry should have included more code. I found out the problem, before i was initializing an object Node and then creating a pointer to that object, and then only removing the pointer, so i updated it and now it works like this. However there are still some weird bugs, it prints 0, 3 and segmentation fault, when it should give segmentation fault right away. What could the problem be now? :/

Answer (score 1):

It would make a lot more sense to recast this as a destructor:

```
class Node {
public:
    // some constructor, methods, ...
    // destructor
    ~Node();
private:
    int key;
    double data;
    Node * right;
    Node * left;
};

Node::~Node(){
    delete left;
    delete right;
    left = right = nullptr; // see note below
};
```

Then all you need is `delete node;` wherever you want to delete the tree. But if it's a subtree you also need to ensure that the parent's pointer to this node is also nulled so that you don't double-delete.

Comment: I tried, doesn't seem to make a difference from what I tried in the OP :( Perhaps the problem is with how i initilize my nodes? I updated the OP with how I do that :) Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think your problem is due to incorrect initialization of the struct Node. Since you erase all the tree recursively, you must ensure that only delete allocated dynamic memory, ie you must ensure that only delete nodes for which you have reserved dynamic memory, otherwise this will compile but will generate error at run time. That said, the correct initialization of a node before joining the tree structure should be as follows:

```
struct Node myNode:
myNode.right=NULL;
myNode.left=NULL;
```

With the above we ensure that the terminal nodes of the tree point to the NULL address, and so when we delete recursively, we will only remove nodes that do not point to this address. Then the new code for the function void delete_tree(Node * & p) Then code for function works:

```
void delete_tree(Node * & p){
 if (p->left){
  delete_tree(p->left);//Only deleted if p->left is different from NULL
 }
 if (p->right){
  delete_tree(p->right);//Only deleted if p->right is different from NULL
 }
 delete p;
 p=NULL; //Good Programming Practice
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried this solution but I run into the same problem as I do in the OP. Perhaps the problem is with how i initilize my nodes? I updated the OP with how I do that :)